# Difference in regex split Java and Python

Tags: java, python, regex, split

I am trying to copy a Java program over to Python, however the Regex splitting appears to work differently in the two languages and I can't figure out why.

In Python:

```
re.split("[^aeiouy]+", "test")
```

Produces:

```
['', 'e', '']
```

In Java:

```
"test".split("[^aeiouy]+");
```

Produces:

```
['', 'e']
```

Why is Java producing a different result and is it possible to emulate Javas .split behaviour in Python?

Comment: If you look at [the Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)), you can see that trailing empty strings are removed.

Comment: @Phylogenesis Completely overlooked that, thanks :)

Comment: To answer the second part, `"test".split("[^aeiouy]+", -1);` will [include trailing empty strings](http://ideone.com/TeG80H).

Comment: Behaviour of regex is very very different accross languages. Even if it is not related to regex, it starts with "escaping" characters in different languages. Some need only `\d`, some need `\\d` - some also need `\\\\d` (cause first, double slashes are removed by the string compiler, then double slashes are removed by the regex engine, leading to exactly `\d` hitting the regex engine). On top of that, not even all options are available in every language... Just don't copy regex-patterns, create them...

Comment: On `split()` commands it is also different. Some languages consider the split-character another hit (i.e. `t;e` -> `t,;,e`, others drop it -> `t,e` - others give "options" to control this.)